# Dependency Injection in service and for web application

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, windows-services, ninject, ninject-extensions

I use dependency injection for my business layer, which contains services, such as my example one below:

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    private IMyDbContext DbContext;

    public MyService(IMyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public DoSomething(int id)
    {
        // Use the business layer for something
        var user = this.DbContext.Set<User>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

As you can see, my service has my Entity Framework DbContext as a dependency.  I am using Ninject as my IoC Container, but I think this could apply to any.

**ASP.NET MVC Website Configuration**

For my ASP.NET Website, I have this configured using Ninject to create a single `IMyDbContext` per request and only one instance of `IMyService` is required per request - so it's nice and straightforward.

- IMyService - Transient
- IMyDbContext - Per Request

**Windows Service Configuration**

I wish to configure it so that for each iteration of my Window Service, that I don't have to 'new up' my service for every iteration.

I want to have the following configuration:

- IMyService - Single Instance or transient
- IMyDbContext - New instance every time a method is called

### The Problem

How can this be achieved when I am sharing my services between the two different projects.

My friend suggested to use a Factory for my `IDbContext`, which would be fine if I didn't want to continue using `Per Request Scope` within my ASP.NET application - but I do.  I'm not sure that I can configure a factory to return the same instance every time just for this purpose and a new instance for each request in my Windows Service.

The problem with this is, for example if I use a factory now (for the Windows Service that requires a new instance for every call to `DoSomething()`):

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    private IMyContextFactory DbContextFactory;

    public MyService(IMyContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        this.DbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public DoSomething(int id)
    {
        // Get instance of the db for use
        var dbContext = this.DbContextFactory.GetInstance();

        // Use the business layer for something
        var user = dbContext.Set<User>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've had to add a line of code in now to make use of the factory.

This no longer works for my website that wants to make use of a single (per request) instance of the DbContext.

I need a configuration that will work for both scenarios as I'm sharing the code base.

I already have a boostrapper for both projects that configures the `kernel` bindings, it's just **how** I configure my bindings for different scenarios whilst sharing a code base.

Comment: what do you mean by 'sharing the services between the two projects'? are you using the same Ninject code to setup your dependencies for both asp.net mvc and windows service project. normally, every host decides the lifetime/injection of the components.. and it looks like your mvc host is at a different wavelength than the windos service. hence they should have their own ninject registrations.

Comment: Each project has own Composition Root. Since they are two different projects, each project should have own Kernel.

Comment: Win is right; more details here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Yes I have a separate bootstrapper for the website and for the windows service.  The problem is that I want to configure the DbContext as PerRequest (the same instance for all requests) for the website and as multiple instances (a new one for each call) for the Windows Service.  However, they share the same code base (the services are the business layer).

Comment: So how can I configure them differently but have the same code in the business layer when I want different behaviours.  For example, if I chose to use a factory and got my context from the factory Eg `var dbContext = DbContextFactory.GetInstance() ` it has code that refers to the factory now, so I don't have use of my singleton anymore for my web application.

Comment: @Coutlon, you shouldn't have to configure anything differently in your business layer. I've never used ninject, but my container of choice would allow me to register dependencies with individual life times. Regardless, If you have 2 roots, and therefore 2 kernels, you should also have two separate registrations. In your MVC application you would register the dependencies of your BLL service as per request, and in your windows service, register your BLL dependencies as transient or whatever else is desired. Seems pretty straight forward unless I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

1. because the MVC and Windows Service are two different hosts, with differing requirements on the lifetime of the injected dependencies, they should have their own Ninject registrations. MVC will define IMyService differently then the Windows Service Host.
2. if that is not possible and you have to use the same ninject registration code for both of your hosts, then the type of application can be a named discrimator to create the instance of IMyService.

   ```
   kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().Named("MVC"); // add lifetime thingy
   kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().Named("WindowsService"); // add lifetime


   // usage
   var iammvc= kernel.Get<IMyService>("MVC");
   ```

if Ninject gets "MVC", you could set it up 1 way, and if it gets "WindowsService", you could set it up differently.

option 1 is normally preferred, since MVC and Windows Service have different execution contexts (Http Request n all) and it is easier to control their dependencies independently.

Answer (score 0):

I had it pointed out to me that the factory extension makes use of `IResolutionRoot` to resolve the dependencies.

This means that when the factory creates an instance, it creates it according to the existing configuration of the type as in the bindings.

If I set the following binding:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyDbContext>().To<MyDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

When I call my factory, it will return the same instance for each call to the factory:

```
// All of these will return the same DbContext
var dbContext1 =  this.DbContextFactory.Create();
var dbContext2 =  this.DbContextFactory.Create();
var dbContext3 =  this.DbContextFactory.Create();
```

Whereas, for my Window Service I wanted it to be a new instance every time, I set the DbContext to transient:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyDbContext>().To<MyDbContext>().InTransientScope();
```

Then I can call the Factory within my service:

```
// This will return a new instance of my DbContext every time
var dbContext1 =  this.DbContextFactory.Create();
var dbContext2 =  this.DbContextFactory.Create();
var dbContext3 =  this.DbContextFactory.Create();
```

Here's the binding for the factory:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyDbContextFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Here's the interface for the Factory:

```
public interface IMyDbContextFactory
{
    IMyDbContext Create();
}
```